# "Entry point was not found" EntryPointNotFoundException when requesting WebAPI methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am working on asp.net web API and I am trying to cal the API method.I am getting this Exception on calling the API methods in mvc4. Please help me to find where I am going wrong.As I am very new to WEB API in asp.net

I put the debugger for that method. its not hitting over it at all,Instead its showing exception.any suggestion is accepted.

And the exception was:

```
Entry point was not found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.]
   System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyScope.GetServices(Type serviceType) +0
   System.Web.Http.Services.DefaultServices.GetServices(Type serviceType) +131
   System.Web.Http.ServicesExtensions.GetServices(ServicesContainer services) +63
   System.Web.Http.ServicesExtensions.GetExceptionLoggers(ServicesContainer services) +26
   System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionServices.CreateLogger(ServicesContainer services) +29
   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ServicesContainer.CreateExceptionServicesLogger() +21
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +180
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +11741313
   System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionServices.GetLogger(ServicesContainer services) +38
   System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionServices.GetLogger(HttpConfiguration configuration) +40
   System.Web.Http.HttpServer.get_ExceptionLogger() +32
   System.Web.Http.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +691
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   System.Web.Http.WebHost.<ProcessRequestAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() +359
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) +71
   System.Web.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +11
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9644097
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0
```

This is the controller code:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// gets the published levels
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="subModuleID"></param>
        /// <param name="parentId"></param>
        /// <returns>List of published levels</returns>
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [ActionName("GetAllPublishedLevel")]

        public List<OMLevelsBALDTO> GetAllPublishedLevel(int submoduleId, int? parentId)
        {
            return businessprovider.GetAllPublishedLevel(submoduleId,parentId);
        }
```

I am calling the web api method using the following url:
http://localhost:30543/api/Levels/GetAllPublishedLevel?submoduleId=3&parentId=2

Comment: You shouldn't be posting screen shots of exception messages because screenshots cannot be indexed for search purposes.

Comment: Please post your controller code so we can see how your API endpoint is defined

Comment: I will post the controller method.

Comment: What class is your Controller extending?

Comment: API controller class